# Using Featuretools to aggregate per time time of day

Tags: feature-extraction, feature-engineering, featuretools

I'm wondering if there's any way to calculate all the same variables I already am using deep feature synthesis (ie counts, sums, mean, etc) for different time segments within a day?

I.e. count of morning events (hours 0-12) as a separate variable from evening events (13-24).

Also, within the same vein, what would be the easiest to get counts by day of week, day of month, day of year, etc. Custom aggregate primitives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. First, let's generate some random data and then I'll walkthrough how

```
import featuretools as ft
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make some random data
n = 100
events_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id" : range(n),
    "customer_id": np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c"], n),
    "timestamp": pd.date_range("Jan 1, 2019", freq="1h", periods=n),
    "amount": np.random.rand(n) * 100 
})

def to_part_of_day(x):
    if x < 12:
        return "morning"
    elif x < 18:
        return "afternoon"
    else:
        return "evening"

events_df["time_of_day"] = events_df["timestamp"].dt.hour.apply(to_part_of_day)

events_df
```

the first thing we want to do is add a new column for the segment we want to calculate features for

```
def to_part_of_day(x):
    if x < 12:
        return "morning"
    elif x < 18:
        return "afternoon"
    else:
        return "evening"

events_df["time_of_day"] = events_df["timestamp"].dt.hour.apply(to_part_of_day)
```

now we have a dataframe like this

```
   id customer_id           timestamp     amount time_of_day
0   0           a 2019-01-01 00:00:00  44.713802     morning
1   1           c 2019-01-01 01:00:00  58.776476     morning
2   2           a 2019-01-01 02:00:00  94.671566     morning
3   3           a 2019-01-01 03:00:00  39.271852     morning
4   4           a 2019-01-01 04:00:00  40.773290     morning
5   5           c 2019-01-01 05:00:00  19.815855     morning
6   6           a 2019-01-01 06:00:00  62.457129     morning
7   7           b 2019-01-01 07:00:00  95.114636     morning
8   8           b 2019-01-01 08:00:00  37.824668     morning
9   9           a 2019-01-01 09:00:00  46.502904     morning
```

Next, let's load it into our entityset

```
es = ft.EntitySet()
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="events",
                         time_index="timestamp",
                         dataframe=events_df)

es.normalize_entity(new_entity_id="customers", index="customer_id", base_entity_id="events")

es.plot()
```

[image]

Now, we are ready to set the segments we want to create aggregations for by using `interesting_values`

```
es["events"]["time_of_day"].interesting_values = ["morning", "afternoon", "evening"]
```

Then we can run DFS and place the aggregation primitives we want to do on a per segment basis in the `where_primitives` parameter

```
fm, fl = ft.dfs(target_entity="customers",
                entityset=es,
                agg_primitives=["count", "mean", "sum"],
                trans_primitives=[],
                where_primitives=["count", "mean", "sum"])

fm
```

In the resulting feature matrix, you can now see we have aggregations per morning, afternoon, and evening

```
             COUNT(events)  MEAN(events.amount)  SUM(events.amount)  COUNT(events WHERE time_of_day = afternoon)  COUNT(events WHERE time_of_day = evening)  COUNT(events WHERE time_of_day = morning)  MEAN(events.amount WHERE time_of_day = afternoon)  MEAN(events.amount WHERE time_of_day = evening)  MEAN(events.amount WHERE time_of_day = morning)  SUM(events.amount WHERE time_of_day = afternoon)  SUM(events.amount WHERE time_of_day = evening)  SUM(events.amount WHERE time_of_day = morning)
customer_id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
a                       37            49.753630         1840.884300                                           12                                          7                                         18                                          35.098923                                        45.861881                                        61.036892                                        421.187073                                      321.033164                                     1098.664063
b                       30            51.241484         1537.244522                                            3                                         10                                         17                                          45.140800                                        46.170996                                        55.300715                                        135.422399                                      461.709963                                      940.112160
c                       33            39.563222         1305.586314                                            9                                          7                                         17                                          50.129136                                        34.593936                                        36.015679                                        451.162220                                      242.157549                                      612.266545
```